# How to make a multiple view app with a class linked to each view

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

Apologies if this has been replied already, I've been searching and I quiet cannot find what I am looking for.

I am trying to make a multiple view application (based on the single view template) and I want to have an object linked to each of the views.
So my intention is to have the same I have coming from the single view template: 1 view on the storyboard which is linked to the ViewController class.

I found some tutorials by using Navigation Controllers, Page View controllers, etc... but I don't want to use that functionality, I prefer to create my own buttons and link them to those pages.

I have a few questions, if you can help:
1 - Should I have an array of view objects?
I've seen an old tutorial where the guy creates a new view object when a button  is pressed and then set the view as modal (which leads to the other class) and afterwards it destroys it immediately (I guess when the code come back once the modal view is closed).
In my case I would like to have an array of views and initialize all of them at the beginning of the app and just swap from one to the other depending on the user actions.
Which one is a better approach?

2 - How I create the class linked to the other view?
Can I create a normal class and make it subclass of UIViewController, is that enough or I need something else?

3 - Once I have the class created, how can I 'link' it to a view on the storyboard?
Basically I would like to have the outlets of each view in its correspondent class (and actions, etc...).

I am not sure if what I am trying to do is actually the correct way, any comments or help is more than appreciated :)

EDIT: I´ve managed to create a class, link it to a view of the storyboard and lunch it when the user press a button, but the new view appears completely black - any ideas?

Here is my code:

TestView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestView : UIViewController

@end
```

TestView.m:

```
#import "TestView.h"

@interface TestView ()

@end

@implementation TestView

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@end
```

Then in the storyboard, I dragged in a new View, and in the "Identity Inspector" in the field "Class" I selected the TestView.

The in the file ViewController (the one created by default by the single view wizard), I added an action when a button is pressed:

```
- (IBAction)goToView1:(id)sender
{
    [self presentViewController:view1 animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Also in the ViewController, function 'ViewDidLoad' I initialize the TestView class:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    view1 = [[TestView alloc] init];
}
```

So when I pressed the button it seems is doing something right or attempting to move to a different view, but the whole screen appears black - Am I missing something?

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: You can navigate between view controller-owned views using custom transitions (not e.g. a navigation controller) if you set them up using a storyboard. Search for "iOS 8 storyboard tutorials".

Comment: Mostly what I found on google is about auto layout.
I found a couple of tutorials but they use old versions of xcode (and interface builder) where there is a wizard to create a view class which already generates everything, but in the current version of xcode I can't find such wizard - if anyone know how to use the wizard (with Objective-C) that would be great.

Comment: You mean Xcode 5/iOS 7? It shouldn't be *that* different. And I'm sure there's iOS 8 stuff too. The "wizard" you are referring to, is it the dialog that appears when you create a new class? Just go to "File -> New> -> File... -> Cocoa Class" and make your custom class a subclass of UIView.

Comment: Regarding your edits... You mentioned your view appears completely black. Did you set your view controller's view class to your custom view subclass in Interface Builder, or is it still the default `UIView`? Does it have any subviews (buttons, labels etc.)? did you try setting its background color to -say- red?

Comment: It's the default (white background) and I just added a label saying "View 1" to identify it. Also the status bar disappears.
I am wondering if the problem is because I have two classes UIViewController, and only the main one should be UIViewController and the other should be only UIView?

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint or an `NSLog()` in your view controller's `-viewDidLoad` method, to see if it is actually called. Also, calling your class `TestView` is confusing; it suggests that it's a subclass of `UIView`. Perhaps `TestViewController` is a better name.

Comment: This part doesn't make sense: "Then in the storyboard, I dragged in a new View, and in the "Identity Inspector" in the field "Class" I selected the TestView.". You class TestView is actually a view controller, not a view.

Comment: I've put a NSLog in the viewDidLoad and the log appeared once the 'black screen' appeared, so I guess that is a good signal.

Sorry about the confusion, so what I mean is that I created the class (without any wizard, just by creating a new .h and .m file) and then, in the storyboard I added a new 'view' object (from the object library into the storyboard).

Comment: Then I selected this new view and in the 'Identity Inspector' (3rd button in the right section of XCode - where the different inspectors are), if you look, the first field that appears is called 'Class' and there you can chose any existing class in the project, so I linked the TestView that I created.

You're right about the name, sorry it was just a test, but I'm a bit confused about the difference between the UIView and the UIViewController, which one should I use in this case?

Comment: Is it possible the black screen appears because the second UIViewController is not 'added' to the window object?
I am really confused about this and I would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance